# How to terminate the instruction in emacs?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run some instructions, I want to cancel it. How can I do it?

I pressed ctrl+C, but it didn't work.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32075/how-to-terminate-the-instruction-in-emacs?/) by [Jui Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2167/jui-wang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to Ctrl+G. In terminal emulator in Emacs you should to use Ctrl+C twice.

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2